# Explicitly assign async pipe fetched result in template variable

Tags: angular

Is is possible to explicitly assign value fetched by `async` pipe to a template variable?

In following example `userList` is assigned the `length` of the fetched value. I would like it to be the fetched result instead. I would also like to show user list or the `noResult` template message based on fetched result's length.

```
<ng-template #noResult> <p> No result to display</p> </ng-template>
<div *ngIf="(userList$ | async)?.length; else noResult; let userList">

 <ul *ngFor="let user of userList">
  <li> {{ user.email }} </li>
 </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

from Angular 4 you can do this

```
<div *ngIf="(userList$ | async) as userList; else noResult;">
  <div *ngIf="userList?.length">
    <ul *ngFor="let user of userList">
      <li> {{ user.email }} </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

online demo here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/5lvn5kCDHtsP2PlTaRmo?p=preview